# How can I force a page language from servlet or jsp so angularjs will pick it up?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, servlets

Angularjs form validation messages are required to always display in French on a given web page. They are displaying correctly in French language browsers but not in an English-language browser.

I do not want to detect the locale in the latter case, it is incorrect for my needs. Instead I want to tell the JavaScript this page/browser is French. Nor do I want to switch language dynamically client-side in JavaScript.

I tried modifying the HTTP headers this way:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Locale" %> 
<%
    Locale locale = new Locale("fr","ca");
    response.setLocale(locale);
    response.setHeader("Content-Language", "fr");
    response.setHeader("Language", "fr");
%>
```

but it does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I already tried <html lang="fr"> and <html lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replacing angularjs with my own JS code. The approach is the same, cycle through all HTML input tags in JavaScript, then search for a custom attribute. If it's there, change the language based on the html tag's lang attribute. Hope this is helpful for someone.

web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>LGS Test Java Login</title>
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">  
      <style>
        .panel-info 
        {
            border-color: #5F4793;
        }

        .panel-info > .panel-heading 
        {
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #5F4793;
            border-color: #5F47931;
         }

         .btn-primary 
         {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #5F4793;
            border-color: #5F4793;
        }  

        .btn-primary:hover 
        {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4c0080;
          border-color: #4c0080;
        }

        .btn-primary:focus,
        .btn-primary.focus 
        {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4c0080;
          border-color: #4c0080;
        }

        .btn-primary:active,
        .btn-primary.active,
        .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary
        {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4c0080;
          border-color: #4c0080;
        }

        .btn-primary:active:hover,
            .btn-primary.active:hover,
        .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover,
        .btn-primary:active:focus,
        .btn-primary.active:focus,
        .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus,
        .btn-primary:active.focus,
        .btn-primary.active.focus,
        .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus 
        {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4c0080;
          border-color: #4c0080;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 style="text-align:center; color:#5F4793;">Test</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div id="panel-heading" class="panel-    heading">Connectez-vous !</div>
                    <div id="messages"></div>
                    <div class="panel-body" >
                        <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm"     method="post" action="loginServlet">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group" id="div1">
                                    <input type="email" bert="required email" class="form-control" id="myLogin" name="uLogin" placeholder="Votre courriel" 
                                style="position: relative; top: 1px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="">
                                    <label for="uLogin" class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="position: relative; top: 1px;">    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group" id="div2">
                                    <input type="password" bert="required" class="form-control" id="myPassword" name="uPassword" 
                                style="position: relative; top: 1px;" placeholder="Votre mot de passe" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                                    <label for="uPassword" class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="position: relative; top: 1px;"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div>
                               <input id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" value="Connectez"></a>
                            </div>
                        </form>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            </div>
        </div> <!--  row  -->      
    </div> <!-- container -->.
    <script src="js/bertrand.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And bertrand.js file:

```
/*
     Small footprint JavaScript library inspired by AngularJS that allows better control of the bootstrap tooltip message wording.

     Depends on: bootstrap.js, required to be placed at bottom of HTML, has to do with DOM loading.

     Contrary to AngularJS, does not rely on browser language to determine validation message language, uses html tag's lang attribute value.
 */
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click",validateForm); }, 500);

/*  BEGIN BLOCK
    get page language from html tag; this works around AngularJS bug as described at:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460174/how-can-i-force-a-page-language-from-servlet-or-jsp-so-angularjs-will-pick-it-up
*/
var mylanguage = "fr";

var myhtmlelement = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
for (var i = 0; i < myhtmlelement.length; i++) /* we should have only one of course */
{
    var attrib =  myhtmlelement[i].attributes;

    for (var x = 0; x < attrib.length; x++) 
    {
        if (attrib[x].name === 'lang') 
        {
            mylanguage = attrib[x].value;
        }
    }
}
/* END BLOCK */

setTimeout(adaptPlaceholder(mylanguage), 500);

var whitespace = " \t\n\r";

function isEmpty(s)
{   return ((s == null) || (s.length == 0));
}

// Returns true if string s is empty or whitespace characters only.
function isWhitespace(s)
{   
    var i;

    // Is s empty?
    if (isEmpty(s)) return true;

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {   
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (whitespace.indexOf(c) == -1) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function isEmail(s)
{   
    if (isWhitespace(s)) return false;

    var i = 1;
    var sLength = s.length;

    while ((i < sLength) && (s.charAt(i) != "@"))
    { 
        i++;
    }

    if ((i >= sLength) || (s.charAt(i) != "@")) return false;
    else i += 2;

    while ((i < sLength) && (s.charAt(i) != "."))
    { 
        i++;
    }

    if ((i >= sLength - 1) || (s.charAt(i) != ".")) return false;
    else return true;
}

function validateForm()
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var shipthis = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
    {
        var attrib =  elements[i].attributes;

        for (var x = 0; x < attrib.length; x++) 
        {
            /* find tags with custom attribute "bert" in them */
            if (attrib[x].name === 'bert') 
            {
                $(elements[i]).closest('div').removeClass("input-group").removeClass("has-error").addClass("input-group has-success");
                if(attrib[x].value.indexOf('email') > -1)
                {
                    if(!isEmail(elements[i].value))
                    {
                        $(elements[i]).closest('div').removeClass("input-group").removeClass("has-success").addClass("input-group has-error");

                        for (var z = 0; z < attrib.length; z++) 
                        {
                            // add supported translations here, or default to French:
                            if (attrib[z].name === 'title') 
                            {
                                if(mylanguage == "en")
                                {
                                    attrib[z].value = "Please enter a valid email address here";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    attrib[z].value = "SVP modifier pour une adresse de courriel valide";
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $(elements[i]).tooltip('show');

                        shipthis = false;
                    }
                }

                if( attrib[x].value.indexOf('required') > -1 )
                {
                    if(isEmpty(elements[i].value))
                    {
                        $(elements[i]).closest('div').removeClass("input-group").removeClass("has-success").addClass("input-group has-error");
                        for (var y = 0; y < attrib.length; y++) 
                        {
                            if (attrib[y].name === 'title') 
                            {
                                // add supported translations here, or default to French:
                                if(mylanguage == 'en')
                                {
                                    attrib[y].value = "Please add a value here";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    attrib[y].value = "SVP ajouter une valeur ici";
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $(elements[i]).tooltip('show');
                        shipthis = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } /* end for get attributes in elements */
    } /* end for get elements with input tag */

    if(shipthis)
    {
        var myform = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
        myform[0].submit();
    }
}

function adaptPlaceholder(mylanguage)
{
    if(mylanguage == "en")
    {
        var el = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) 
        {
            var attrib =  el[i].attributes;

            for (var x = 0; x < attrib.length; x++) 
            {
                if(el[i].type == "email")
                {
                    if (attrib[x].name == "placeholder") 
                    {
                        attrib[x].value = "Your email address";
                    }
                }
                else if(el[i].type == "password")
                {
                    if (attrib[x].name == "placeholder") 
                    {
                        attrib[x].value = "Your password";
                    }
                }
                else if(el[i].type == "button")
                {
                    if (attrib[x].name == "value") 
                    {
                        attrib[x].value = "Connect";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("panel-heading").innerHTML = 'Connect !';
    }
}
```